# Where should I put MPI_INIT in a Fortran module?

Tags: fortran, mpi, modulo, subroutine

I have a problem, and I don't know what it is. I have a test program with MPI_INIT and MPI_FINALIZE in its body. I have a module that contains 5 subroutines: 3 subroutines are dependent, and independent from 2 other subroutines. I want to put the MPI code in the test program into this module. I put MPI_INIT in the module where the variables are declared and before the subroutine. I obtain a series of errors with the same error message:

```
This statement must not appear in the specification part of a module
```

How does "MPI_INIT and MPI_FINALIZE should be called only once" affect Fortran program, modules, and subroutines? Where should I put MPI functions and variables if there are multiple, independent programs, each calling this module's subroutines multiple number of times?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updated: Should I put MPI in a module or a module's subroutine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437672/updated-should-i-put-mpi-in-a-module-or-a-modules-subroutine)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call MPI subroutine in subroutine part of the module.

Generally i define an init_mpi subroutine that do the call to MPI_INIT and eventually call to MPI_COMM_RANK and MPI_COMM_SIZE. You could also use MPI_INITIALIZED in this init_mpi subroutine to avoid multiple initialization.